# VBA run function in an access db via another access db

Tags: vba

all I need to run a function that will run multiple reports in different access databases... ad DB to rule them all :)
here the structure: in my multi_report.accdb I have a form with a button that is running this code:

```
Private Sub Comando1_Click()

Dim db_report As String
Dim objAccess As Object
Dim ctr As Date

'TICKETS
db_report = "\\sdocenco01\OPC\11_SCL\TICKETS\ticket.accdb"
Set objAccess = GetObject(db_report) 'opens other db
objAccess.Visible = True
objAccess.Run "report_tickets" 'runs function in other db
objAccess.Quit 'quits other db
Set objAccess = Nothing

'PROCESSI
db_report = "\\sdocenco01\OPC\11_SCL\PROCESSI\utilita.accdb"
Set objAccess = GetObject(db_report)
objAccess.Visible = True
objAccess.Run "report_processi"
objAccess.Quit
Set objAccess = Nothing

...
```

in the line

```
objAccess.Run "report_tickets"
```

i get a run-time error '2517' routine report_tickets not found

I tried different codes like

```
objAccess.Run "ticket.report_tickets"
```

or

```
objAccess.Run "ticket.Database1.report_tickets"
```

but nothing seems to work

in the \sdocenco01\OPC\11_SCL\TICKETS\ticket.accdb i have this code:

```
Public Function report_tickets()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
...
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

First, according to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361), the project name must be included:

> The name of the Function or Sub procedure to be run. If you are
> calling a procedure in another database, use the project name and the
> procedure name separated by a dot in the form:
> "projectname.procedurename"

Next, I guess the "Report_" prefix confuses. Try renaming the functions and call them like:

```
objAccess.Run "YourProjectName.ReportTickets"
```

Comment: See expanded answer, please.

Comment: nope, i tried... still not working... same error

Comment: Then double-check everything. It is tested and runs nicely here

Comment: i actually did naming the function as you suggeste ReportTickets... i really do not know what to do

Comment: Try rebuilding just this from scratch as simple as possible. My `ReportTickets` only popped a `MsgBox`.

Comment: hi gustav thanks actually i follow your suggestions creating a simple function that just open up a message box but no way... it seems we are missing something here...

Comment: Can't tell, sorry. Worked "out of the box" for me.